# How to remove all goto statements in pseudocode?

Tags: ida, hexrays

IDA shows multiple goto statements in the decompiled pseudocode. I've read this manual page: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/config.shtml and tried to disable/enable these flags `MAX_NCOMMAS`, `HO_FAST_STRUCTURAL`, `HO_UNMERGE_TAILS` in `cfg/hexrays.cfg` file. But it doesn't change anything in the pseudocode.

Comment: In that case, Hex-rays may simply not smart enough to eliminate all goto's.

Comment: It does? I don't see the manual shows that. It only says that number of goto may be *reduced*.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you mentioned is `Max commas`.  .

- Edit > Plugins > Hex-ray decompiler > Options > Max commas (default is 8).

*Decrease value*: Hexray uses "goto" statement instead of conditions inside single "if" statement.
*Increase*: Hexray uses "if" statement instead of nested "goto" statement.

However, This is matter of representation, and does not mean remove all "goto" statement.

Answer (score 1):

If Hex-Rays had a way to remove all `goto` statements in the decompilation, then it simply would not generate `goto` statements in the first place. There is no option to do what you are asking.